# Java - How to cast BigInteger set to BigInteger array

Tags: java, biginteger

I have the following code:

```
public static BigInteger[] Cubes (int m){
    Set<BigInteger> result = new HashSet<BigInteger>();

    for (int i = 1;; i++){
        BigInteger check = BigInteger.valueOf(i).pow(3);
        if (String.valueOf(check).length() == m){
            result.add(check);
        }
        if (String.valueOf(check).length() > m) break;
    }

    // I now have a BigInteger set containing all my values. 
   // I need to cast this to a BigInteger[] over here.
   // Then, I can return a BigInteger array.

}
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the Java Collections [toArray() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray(T[])):

```
BigInteger[] output = result.toArray(new BigInteger[result.size()]);
```

Comment: I had actually tried something similiar, but I forgot to add the () after .size